# IndexOutOfBoundException even after explicit check?

Tags: java, jdbc, hive

So I'm creating a HivePreparedStatement and trying to execute it. But that threw an IndexOutOfBounds Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.deleteCharAt(AbstractStringBuilder.java:824)
    at java.lang.StringBuffer.deleteCharAt(StringBuffer.java:441)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.updateSql(HivePreparedStatement.java:142)
    at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HivePreparedStatement.execute(HivePreparedStatement.java:98)
    at my.personal.code.package.AbstractHiveTask.executePreparedSQL(AbstractHiveTask.java:99)
```

This made me dig into HivePreparedStatement's code to figure out what exactly was throwing this exception. I found the following code of `HivePreparedStatement.updateSql` and `getCharIndexFromSqlByParamLocation(...)`

```
/**
   * update the SQL string with parameters set by setXXX methods of {@link PreparedStatement}
   *
   * @param sql
   * @param parameters
   * @return updated SQL string
   */
  private String updateSql(final String sql, HashMap<Integer, String> parameters) {
    if (!sql.contains("?")) {
      return sql;
    }

    StringBuffer newSql = new StringBuffer(sql);

    int paramLoc = 1;
    while (getCharIndexFromSqlByParamLocation(sql, '?', paramLoc) > 0) {
      // check the user has set the needs parameters
      if (parameters.containsKey(paramLoc)) {
        int tt = getCharIndexFromSqlByParamLocation(newSql.toString(), '?', 1);
        newSql.deleteCharAt(tt);
        newSql.insert(tt, parameters.get(paramLoc));
      }
      paramLoc++;
    }

    return newSql.toString();

  }


  /**
   * Get the index of given char from the SQL string by parameter location
   * </br> The -1 will be return, if nothing found
   *
   * @param sql
   * @param cchar
   * @param paramLoc
   * @return
   */
  private int getCharIndexFromSqlByParamLocation(final String sql, final char cchar, final int paramLoc) {
    int signalCount = 0;
    int charIndex = -1;
    int num = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sql.length(); i++) {
      char c = sql.charAt(i);
      if (c == '\'' || c == '\\')// record the count of char "'" and char "\"
      {
        signalCount++;
      } else if (c == cchar && signalCount % 2 == 0) {// check if the ? is really the parameter
        num++;
        if (num == paramLoc) {
          charIndex = i;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return charIndex;
  }
```

The exception is thrown at `newSql.deleteCharAt(tt)` line, leading to conclusion that the `getCharIndexFromSqlByParamLocation` must not be able to find `?` in the string buffer at all. However, the `while` block actually first checks for the existence of `?` at the nth position before asking the `newSql` for the first `?` for the nth time.

(It may be worth noting that I'm using the same `Hive Connection` to execute multiple `PreparedStatements`, but none of the variables in the above methods are static, so I have ruled out thread-unsafety)

How is it possible, then, that that line returns `-1`, when the `while` check has passed?

Comment: `while (getCharIndexFromSqlByParamLocation(sql, '?', paramLoc) > 0)` should probably be `while (getCharIndexFromSqlByParamLocation(newSql.toString(), '?', paramLoc) > 0)`

Comment: I would guess the parameter replacement introduces an odd number of quotes.

Comment: @Eran since this is a well used library code, I think this was intentional, to not go beyond the original number of ?, whatever the parameter replacements was.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, yes, I think you hit the hammer on the head! It was not odd number of quotes, but odd number of backslashes (I think). The library code already escapes all single quotes while setting the string but not all backslashes. I couldn't find the exact payload that was creating the issue, but escaping backslashes seems to have stopped the exceptions.
You could put that in as an answer, and I'd be happy to accept it

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with incorrect analysis of number of special characters (single quotes and backslashes) in sql. Failing on sql with already added parameters with odd number of these symbols.
Fixed in version 2.3.0 of hive-jdbc library.
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13625